# Updating Woo commerce checkout Page with Additional Form Data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I am collecting an additional User Meta Data for my Woo commerce check out page.

```
woocommerce_form_field('myName', array(
    'type' =>'text',
    'class'=>array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'=>__('First Name'),
    'placeholder'=>__('Please enter your name'),
), $checkout->get_value('myName'));
```

And I am updating to the database with this code:

```
/*Update the info with the checkout*/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_field_update_order_meta','my_custom_checkout_field_update_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_meta($order_id){
    if($_POST['MyName'])
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'First Name',esc_attr($POST['MyName']));
}
```

Each time I submit, I get an internal server Error, even though I am working on a local machine. I need to collect that data and persist it into the order Database. Anybody help?

Comment: `esc_attr($POST['MyName'])` is not an array. i guess it should be `esc_attr($_POST['MyName'])` also check apache `error_logs` there must be syntax error. 500 internal server Error in simple words is script error.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the server error is gone, but I didn't get the additional field in my order details. Am i missing something?

Comment: where do you want this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Normally the postmeta `meta_key` should not use white spaces and capitals…

Also your additional field should need to be inside the checkout form, if not nothing will be submitted and nothing can be saved.

To display an custom text field and save it in the database once submitted, the best way is to use the following:

```
// Add checkout custom text field
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'add_checkout_custom_field', 20, 1 );
function add_checkout_custom_field( $checkout) {

    // Text field
    woocommerce_form_field('my_name', array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'class'       => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'       => __('First Name'),
        'placeholder' =>__('Please enter your name'),
    ), $checkout->get_value('my_name') );
}

// Save the data to the order
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order','my_custom_checkout_field_update_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_meta( $order ){
    if( isset($_POST['my_name']) && ! empty($_POST['my_name']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '_my_name', sanitize_text_field($POST['my_name']) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works…

To get this data once saved in the order, use `get_post_meta( $order_id, '_my_name', true );` where `$order_id` is the dynamic order ID…

Your additional text field will be located just before "Order notes" field:

[image]

> Now your **additional field** is confusing as Billing and Shipping **first name** fields already exist in checkout page.

Comment: am still not getting the additional field on the front end. Kindly advice further.

Comment: @olasunkanmi I have added some details in my answer… This code is tested and works. You can check it in [**this test server**](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/tie3/shop/) where you can add a product to cart and have a look in checkout…

Comment: I have corrected my mistakes, So far I have managed to collect store and update, but right now, I only have the colomn name show up in the order form without the data that was collected itself. Like First Name : Blank.

Comment: with this get_post_meta( $order->id, '_my_name', true )